# Is there a way to get a FIDE ID without playing in FIDE rated events?

Tags: rating, fide

Is there a way to obtain FIDE ID, also known as FID, without actually participating in FIDE rated events? I don't mean obtaining a FIDE rating, just the ID.

The reason why I am asking is simple: this summer I am going to Pardubice Czech Open and I would like to invite my father with me. I myself have a FIDE ID, but my father doesn't, and he lives in an area where FIDE rated events don't happen often so it is quite unlikely he can get FIDE id through playing in a tournament before Czech Open.

The issue is that according to the Czech Open rules foreign players must possess a FIDE ID to take part in their rated tournaments, so it might be so that my father won't be able to participate.

He has a national rating around 2150.

Is there a way to just get registered by FIDE and get an ID or something like that? Maybe through [FIDE online arena](https://arena.myfide.net/)? I have created an account for him on there and entered all the personal information, but it appears that to have his official online rating calculated we need to pay 25 euros fee. Not a big deal, but I am reluctant to do so without having some assurance that this will result into assigning FIDE ID for him.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

See the licensing regulations from [FIDE Handbook](http://www.fide.com/fide/handbook.html?id=180&view=article), particularly 1.13.3.

> 1.1   Registration is the procedure of entering a player’s personal details into the FIDE players’ database.
>
> 1.2   A player registered to FIDE acquires a FIDE ID number (FIN).
>
> ...
>
> 1.13  Registration can be made in 4 different ways:
>
> - 1.13.1     National Rating Officers can register new players associated with their own National Federation and ‘FIDE flag players’.
> - 1.13.2     The FIDE Rating Administrator may register new players under special circumstances only, in FIDE events. In this case the
>     Chief Arbiter and the Organiser are responsible for providing correct
>     players' data. FIDE events are all competitions under the aegis of a)
>     the World Championship & Olympiad Commission or Events Commission, b)
>     Continental competitions that provide qualifiers to any of the
>     aforesaid competitions, and c) events listed and described in detail
>     in different parts of the FIDE Handbook.
> - 1.13.3     New players may register themselves in FIDE Online Arena playing zone (FOA). These players are not associated to any National
>     Federation, but they are assigned the FIDE flag (FID) until they
>     become members of a National Federation.
> - 1.13.4     When a child registers at sm.fide.com he/she will be allocated a FIDE ID. If such person already had a FIDE ID before that
>     registration, his/her FIDE ID will be retained and a new one will not
>     be given. After upgrading to Premium at psm.fide.com, a child gets a
>     CiS rating.

Comment: I registered online, and I have a FIDE ID. But it does not appear in the website. Shall I wait a couple of days or more?

Answer (score 10):

The resolution of my problem turned out to be pretty simple. I emailed to my national federation and asked if they could create FIDE id for my father. They said they could so I emailed his personal information to them and in a few hours they emailed his newly created FIDE id to me. Happy ending :)

Comment: You are lucky to have his ID emailed in a few hours ;)