# Associating myself with my FIDE chess profile

Tags: fide, websites

I have a USCF rating, but never had a FIDE rating.  Two of the recent tournaments I played in were USCF/FIDE events.  As a result, I now have a FIDE ID, and a "FIDE Chess Profile" page on the FIDE site.  (This happened without my knowledge, but I wanted to "eventually" get a FIDE rating anyway, so I'm very pleased.)

How do I create a login/password **and associate** myself (real life) with that chess profile?  (The bold part is the important part.)  Specifically, on the FIDE Chess Profile page in question, there are login/password fields on the right side - but since I never initiated getting the ID in the first place, I'm not sure how to let FIDE know that I'm me. I would think this information/process would be easy to find, but I'm having trouble locating it...

This is sort of similar to [this question](https://chess.stackexchange.com/questions/14169/is-there-a-way-to-get-a-fide-id-without-playing-in-fide-rated-events) about obtaining a FIDE ID without having played a FIDE event - but I apparently already have the ID.

(For the record, the name/birthday/etc. are all correct, as are the specific tournaments and opponents I played in.  I am 100% certain that this really is me.)

Comment: I think you gave your email to TD, that's how they associate.

Comment: @CognisMantis You are correct: following Brian Towers' answer, below, e-mail was one of the associated fields to match.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Getting a login is easy, free and worthwhile if you want to see your or other players' histories (ratings, titles, performance, etc.) If you click on the link on your FIDE ratings page where it says "Get rating" next to "Online rating not rated" it will take you to the [FIDE Online Arena](https://arena.myfide.net/) page. Underneath the banner on that page is a menu item "Registration and fees" and in the drop down list when you hover over it is the item "[Memberships](https://arena.myfide.net/registration-and-fees/memberships)"

That memberships page describes the different levels of membership available - "Guest Member", "FIDE Member", "Platinum Service". Guest membership is free and is what I have but it does not associate me with my FIDE profile. To do that I would have to join as a FIDE member and pay them 25 euros. On the form that comes up when I want to join as a FIDE member are entries for my name, date of birth, gender email address, FIDE number and the username and password I want to use. For the association to work the details I give would have to match those that FIDE have for me in their database.

Comment: This worked perfectly - thanks!  For some reason, I had assumed (and we know what that does) that the 'Get Rating' had to do with the online rating and nothing more, and hadn't investigated that link further...